# Is it possible to pull ipynb from repo using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to store .ipnyb files in a git repository and pull them if needed, from Jupyter Notebook? For example by typing `git pull something` in the cell and executing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute external programs from within Jupyter Notebook by prepending them with exclamation mark.

Example:

```
!uname -a
```